# Can't get data - sqlite3

Tags: objective-c, ios

I use sqlite for my simple iOS app. The problem is that I can't get the result from the query. I will skip the code which is responsible for opening the database. It works.

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM tickets LIMIT 0,1";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    NSString *strResult = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]; 
            NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
```

Here the app crash with a message:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

I'm 100% sure that the query

```
SELECT * FROM tickets LIMIT 0,1
```

return result which is not NULL. I have tested the query above with sqlite client and it works fine.

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't evaluate your statement. You should use:

```
int sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt*);
```

after `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.